# How to launch a web browser with a POST request without a temporary file in .NET?

Tags: html, .net, post

I need to launch a web browser window from my .NET application that shows a web page that can be arrived to only by a POST request. I am definitely not allowed to do this with a temporary HTML file that contains a POST form. Any ideas how to solve this in another way? I have no idea what browsers are installed on users computers and I do not wish to have any requirements regarding this. Default browser would be the best.

Edit: Ok, as soon as I read my own question, I see one solution: to host e.g. a php script on my own server which would convert GET requests to POST requests and redirects to that web page. That php script can then be accessed with a simple link from my .NET application. Obviously, this involves an additional delay and complicates matters. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no better solution other than the two you describe. https://textslashplain.com/2020/02/05/app-to-web-communication-launching-web-apps/ outlines the problem space.